# jQuery Plugin for Inline Balloon Popup Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

(I don't quite know what to call this kind of control, so if someone can tell me what the name is, I'll edit the question for clarity.)

I'm looking for a jQuery control that will let me make a little pop-up editor that looks like a balloon coming out from a point in the form. In my use case, I'm tight on space and I want to let the user pick a couple of date ranges.

Something like this in the iCloud Calendar new event pop-up:

[image]

Comment: Build it yourself. It's not that difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using qTip2 for jQuery:

http://qtip2.com/

But to get it to put a who div in there, I had to customize the JS a bit:

```
events: {
    show: function(event, api) {
       $("#tooltipContainer").html("");
       $("#btnSelectDatesPopup").detach().appendTo("#tooltipContainer");
       $("#btnSelectDatesPopup").show();
    },
    hide: function(event, api) {
       $("#btnSelectDatesPopup").hide();
       $("#btnSelectDatesPopup").detach().appendTo("#originalSelectDatesPopupContainer");
       $("#tooltipContainer").html("<p>...</p>");
    }
}
```

And on the form submit, close the tooltip if it's not closed already, and put it back into the DOM where it belongs:

```
// On form submit, trigger the tooltip hide to preserve user-chosen values
$("#aspnetForm").submit("submit", function(event) {
    qtipApi.hide();
    setTimeout(function(){}, 300);
});
```